# How do I keep admins on chrome from pushing apps to my personal computer?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I own a MacBook and for school I have to use google chrome because it is the most convenient way to do all of my school stuff. Last year they tried to push LAN School. This would violate my privacy and was not in the handbook that I signed. I had to uninstall it to have them push it a few more times. Is there anything I can set up to take this power away from Chrome? I did not see it in settings that I could find.